Laravel tenant early initialization for multi db system
i am building a laravel multi tenant (each tenant have a seperated db), with tenancyforlaravel package. Now i am building a structure where users can create it own entity like: Cars, Jobs etc. I have done this successfully on the central DB, but am facing a problem when i do  this structure for tenants. First, I create the relevant fields that will be part of an entity, then I create the entity and add the fields I just created, at this moment migrations, models, controllers, resources are created and a db table looks like this:
 select * from entities;
+----+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | order | is_active | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | jobs | 0     |         1 | 2024-05-23 11:51:51 | 2024-05-23 11:51:51 |
+----+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+

This is on tenant db. NOTE: each tenant db has this prefix: tenant and the full table name will be tenant+profilename, in my case: tenantagency;
So far so good. The problem comes when i try to add routes for this entity, and on practice i so something like this:
// tenant.php
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
    InitializeTenancy::class,
])->group(function () {
    ....
    $tenant->get('entity', $baseViewController);
    $tenant->get('fields', $baseViewController);

    // Include custom web entity routes
    require __DIR__.'/tenant/entities/entityRoutesWEB.php';
    ....
});

//  .../entityRoures/php 
$entities = Entities::all();
// dd($entities);
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $entityName = strtolower($entity->name);
    $controllerName = 'App\Http\Controllers\API\Tenant\\' . ucfirst($entityName) . 'Controller';

    // Define routes for this entity
    Route::get("/{$entityName}", [BaseViewController::class, 'index']); // Fetch data for the entity
}   


So my problem is here: `$entities = Entities::all();
// dd($entities);` this is getting the entities from the central db.

    // /Tenant/EntitiesModel.php
    namespace App\Models\Tenant\Entities;
    // /Central/EntitiesModel.php
    namespace App\Models\Central\Entities;

NOTE: Same logic i have used for the central DB and it work.

What is the problem? What are you expecting and what are you getting instead?
